# Rhythm question about piano sheet notation

Tags: piano, learning, rhythm

[image]
[image]

This is a part of the song that I want to play, but I'm not sure how I should play the rhythm in the 19th and 20th segments.

I'm a bit confused over the sixteenth notes, at first I thought the quarter note form the right hand and the sixteenth note from the left is played together. But now that I'm seeing that both hands have 4 sixteenth notes in the same segment I'm thinking that maybe it should be played as an accord together with the left hand (shown in the second picture)?

I hope this was not too confusing.

Thank you in advance.

PS: The link to the full sheet is here: http://sheethost.com/sheet/DbQ9KB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your markings are correct.

Remove the stems-up voice from the RH and all will become clear.

A little more horizontal space would have allowed the engraver to make it rather more clear.   But once you see the pattern of repeated D# 16ths, it's not too bad.

[image]